# Erro ao inserir dados no datagridview

Tags: c#, datagridview

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
public partial class PesquisaAluno : Form
{
    List<ModelAluno> alunos;

    public PesquisaAluno(List<ModelAluno> alunos)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.alunos = alunos;
    }

    private void PesquisaAluno_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dg.DataSource = alunos;

        foreach (var aluno in alunos)
        {
            dg.Rows.Add(aluno.Nome, aluno.Cpf, aluno.Matricula.IdCurso);
        }

    }
```

Esse código é chamado quando a pesquisa no formulário anterior retorna mais de 1 item. Esses resultados são armazenados na lista alunos e passados ao formulário do datagrid. Porém, quando o formulário tenta carregar, ele retorna o seguinte erro:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Não é possível adicionar linhas programaticamente à coleção de linhas de DataGridView quando o controle é associado a dados.'

Como resolver este erro?

Comment: Isso porque, na linha imediatamente acima, você define um DataSource para o Grid. Aliás, por que você está alterando o DataSource e ao mesmo tempo tentando adicionar linhas no Grid? Só alterar o DataSource é suficiente.

Comment: No caso, como estou iniciando na programação, este é meu primeiro projeto com datagridview. Quando recupero os dados apenas pelo datasource, vejo que o grid me apresenta colunas que não quero. Sabendo que eu defini 3 colunas visualmente no datagridview, como faço pra populá-las?